# Change the Views exposed filter from link to select list depending on device size

Tags: views

I have a design that requires a select list for the exposed filter when on mobile/tablet and a link for the desktop version.

I am using better exposed filters for this.

My only idea would be to create 2 separate views, and hide/show them accordingly, however this doesn't seem ideal.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Yes there are many better solutions. The first few that spring to mind: 1. Use CSS on mobile to style the same links like a select list instead. 2. Use JS to convert the links to a select on mobile only. 3. Fire your designer

Comment: Lol Clive hahah